# Rspec testing for uniqueness/duplicate values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to write an rspec test that will detect if different identities have the same values (check uniqueness for provider and id)

Here is the test I'm working on. I just kind of threw some crap into it cause I was getting desperate...

```
context "no duplicate values should exist" do
  identity1 = subject { Factory.create(:valid_identity) }
  it { should be_valid }
  identity2 = identity1
  it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:id) }
  it { should have(1).error_on(:id) }
  it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:provider) }
  it { should have(1).error_on(:provider) }

end
```

To give you an idea of the structure I'm used to, I've written basic tests like the one below and if possible I'd like to stick to the same sort of structure

```
context "when created without a name" do
  subject { Brand.create Factory.build(:valid_brand, :name => nil).attributes }
  it { should be_invalid }
  it { should have(1).error_on(:name) }
  specify { subject.errors[:name].should include "can't be blank" }
end
```

my identity factory is as such :

```
Factory.define :valid_identity, :class => Identity do |identity|
  identity.participant {|participant| participant.association(:valid_participant) }
  identity.provider "twitter"
  identity.extid '11111'
end
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour you want is: when I create a new object and I already have an object in the database with the same provider/id than must the new object be invalid.

In pseudo code this means:

```
# 1. create a totally valid object and save it in the database
obj1 = create_valid_object_and_save_it
# 2. we need a second object that's totally valid when obj1 exists
obj2 = create_second_valid_object_dont_save_it
# 3. we make the bad condition
obj2.provider = obj1.provider
# 4. now comes the actualy test, obj2 must not be valid!
assert ! obj2.valid?
```

If you want to test validations, always start from a valid object and change what you want to be invalid. That way you're sure your test won't fail in the future.